# Trouble with generic function in Swift 3

Tags: swift, function, generics

with the premise that it's the first time I try to understand generic functions, I was wondering what is wrong with the following code (Swift 3):

```
func isTgreatherthanU<T: Comparable, U: Comparable>(t: T, u: U) -> Bool {
    return t > u
}
```

(I know it's a stupid function, but it's only meant to understand how to write generic code.)

The compiler says:

> Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'U'

I thought that, by declaring `T` and `U` as conforming to the Comparable protocol, the code should have worked, but I'm obviously doing something wrong... Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A value of a `Comparable` type can be compared with another value
of *the same type.* In your case, `T` and `U` are unrelated
and possibly different types. For example, you cannot compare a `String` with an `Int` 
even if both types are `Comparable`.

What you want is

```
func isTgreatherthanU<T: Comparable>(t: T, u: T) -> Bool {
    return t > u
}
```

i.e. both arguments are values of the *same* type `T`.

Answer (score 2):

The Swift Standard Library only implements binary operators like `>` to compare two objects of the same type. `T` and `U` conform both to `Comparable`, but they might be of two different types. Swift considers `T` and `U` as different types, no matter which protocols they conform to.

Only something like that would work:

```
func isTgreatherthanU<T: Comparable>(t: T, u: T) -> Bool {
    return t > u
}
```